# Table in MVC4 Razor does not update after picking a value form a DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to update the table rows after choosing a value from the DropDownListFor.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumACTI, Model.NumactItems, "Choisissez un Numero ACTI", new { @id = "ddlTMManagers", onchange = "MyFunction()" })
```

the Ajax function:

```
function MyFunction() {
  var districtId = $('#ddlTMManagers option:selected').text();
  var CodeClient = $('#ddlTextbox').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ListChargement',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ districtId: districtId, CodeClient: CodeClient }),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

the Action in the controller :

```
public ActionResult ListChargement(string districtId, string CodeClient)
{
  return RedirectToAction("Index", new { CodeClient= CodeClient,districtId= districtId });

}
```

I do get the two values "districtId" and "CodeClient"
but the values of the table in the Index does not update.

Comment: the ddl is in the same view?

Comment: You making an ajax call. Ajax calls stay on he same page so `return RedirectToAction("Index"...` is pointless. What exactly are you trying to do. Do you want to update something on the same page (in which case return Json or a partial view and update the DOM) or do you want to redirect (in which case put the dropdown in a form and do a standard submit

Comment: Yes, i only want to update something in the same page

Comment: Then change `ListChargement` to return a partial view or Json (depends what your trying to update in the view), and then in the success function, update the DOM with the return result.

Comment: Thx Stephen it works Finally.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { name = CodeClient, districtId });
```

to

```
return Index( CodeClient, districtId );
```